# string split into array not working

Tags: c#

I am trying to split a string from a text file into an array so that I can store them in a class but it is not working; it doesn't split it, it returns the same format in the textfile.txt

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("textfile.txt"))
{
  string line;
  while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\t' };
    string[] parts = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(parts[i]);
    }

  }
}
```

the text file contains:

```
George\t15\tStudent\tAddress\tB:\temp\profilepic.png
```

I want it to look like this (after the split):

```
George
15
Student
Address
profilepic.png
```

Any ideas or help appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually see `\t` in the file or are you just putting it there for textual representation?

Comment: Do you really have all of those `\t`'s in your text file?   or is that just a way to show the text file contains tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sample line you provided, the closest I think you can get is probably using the following regex, maybe if you play with this you can get it to not give you the path, or alternatively, in your loop you can do a check for path and skip it, this should tell you whether it's a path or not `[a-zA-Z]:\\\w*?\\`

```
string[] results = Regex.Split(line, @"(?<!B:)\\t|(?<=B:\\\w*?\\)");
```

it produces this list:

- George
- 15
- Student
- Address
- B:\temp\
- profilepic.png

Comment: I have to admit that I tried to do it and failed... I need to practice more with regex...  Regex.Split( cadena, @"(?<![a-zA-Z]:)\\t" ) is what I wanted

Answer (score 6):

"\t" is a special character meaning "tab".  If you want to actually look for the string `\t` you need to use `"\\t"` or `@"\t"`.  You don't need to make it a char array either; there's an overload for a string.

Comment: Indeed.  It's a badly formed feed file.

Comment: Well, I definitely think it's badly formed.  It seems clear the intent of the feed file was to make tab-separated data; it is also clear that is not what happened.

Comment: Maybe.. :) but at least it can be parsed... ;)

Comment: Not with `split`, unless you want to concatenate the last 2 (or three, or four) elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `"\\t"` as split **string**. you should get:

George 
15
Student
Address
B:
emp\profilepic.png

Not 
**profilepic.png**

EDIT: `"\\t"` was displayed as `"\t"` in my answer

Comment: note the "B:\t" part of the path, expect "B:" and "emp\profilepic.png"

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having here is with [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx). Character combinations that begin with a '`\`' are considered Escape Sequences, and they act differently than regular strings. As you can see from the table in the link, '`\t`' represents a horizontal tab. So when in C# you use '`\t`' as a delimiter, it looks for a horizontal tab, however your plaintext has the actual sequence of characters '`\t`' in it, which is what you are looking for.

The question then becomes, how do I find '`\t`' if when I use it as a delimiter it searches for horizontal tabs? The answer is also shown in the link; '`\\`' is a representation of '`\`' (and necessary if you think about it, otherwise how could you look for '`\(anything)`'. So your delimiter has to be '`\\t`'.

(Should note that you can do this with string too, without turning everything into a character array, the principle still holds)

Comment: Thanks for the explain, have better understanding  now. I only got one problem though, I get error message saying :Error 1 Too many characters in character literal. how do I fix that?

Comment: @UnknownUser That is happening because '\\t' is 2 characters, it won't fit in one char. You need to change the char deliminators to string seperators (You should note from other's comments that you lose the t from temp when you do it that way)